# Arrays,functions and random

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am doing a project using arrays, functions and random numbers.  When I run the program it gives an error pointing to line 44.  Looking at the code, I can't figure out what the problem is.
The error says: int [i] can not be converted to int in line 44.

Any idea what is wrong?
By the way Can I format this with numbers?

```
// Debugging: grades.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_GRADES = 10;
const int NUM_SUDENTS = 3;

int findHighest( int * );
int findLowest( int * );
void printDatabase( const int [][NUM_GRADES], const char [][ 20 ] );

int main()
{
    int student1[ NUM_GRADES ] = { 0 };
    int student2[ NUM_GRADES ] = { 76, 89, 81, 42, 66, 93, 104,
                                    91, 71, 85 };
    int student3[ NUM_GRADES ] = { 65, 69, 91, 89, 82, 93, 72,
                                    76, 79, 99 };
    char names[ NUM_SUDENTS ][ 20 ] = { "Bob", "John", "Joe" };

    int database[ NUM_SUDENTS ][ NUM_GRADES ];
    int i = 0;

    srand( time( 0 ) );

    // initialize student1
    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++ )
        student1[ NUM_GRADES ] = rand() % 50 + 50;

    // initialize database
    for ( i = 1; i < NUM_GRADES; i++ ) {
        database[ 0 ][ i ] = student1[ i ];
        database[ 1 ][ i ] = student2[ i ];
        database[ 2 ][ i ] = student3[ i ];
    } // end for

    printDatabase( database,  names );

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_SUDENTS; i++ ) {
        cout << names[ i ] << "'s highest grade is: "
        << findHighest(database[i]) << endl           // This is line 44 in my program
        << names[ i ] << "'s lowest grade is: "
        << findLowest( database[ i ] ) << endl;
    } // end for
} // end main

 // determine largest grade
int findHighest( int a[] )
 {
    int highest =  a[ 0 ];
    for ( int i = 1; i <= NUM_GRADES; i++ )
        if ( a[ i ] > highest )
            highest = a[ i ];
     return highest;
 } // end function findHighest

 // determine lowest grade
 int findLowest( int a[] )
 {
    int lowest = a[ 0 ];
    for ( int i = 1; i < NUM_GRADES; i++ )
        if ( a[ i ] < lowest )
            lowest = a[ i ];
    return lowest;
 } // end lowestGrade

 // output data
void printDatabase( int a[][ NUM_GRADES ], char names[][ 20 ] )
{
    cout << "Here is the grade database\n\n"
    << setw( 10 ) << "Name";
    for ( int n = 1; n <= NUM_GRADES; n++ )
        cout << setw( 4 ) << n;
    cout << endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_SUDENTS; i++ ) {
        cout << setw( 10 ) << names[ i ];
        for ( int j = 0; j < NUM_GRADES; j++ )
            cout << setw( 4 ) << a[ i, j ];
        cout << endl;
    } // end for
    cout << endl;
} // end printDatabase
```

Comment: Wow, funny. I pasted the code into my text editor and it told me line 44 was that blank line.

Comment: Why so much code when you know where the error's coming from?

Comment: By the way, after adding the proper include for `srand`, there are no compiler errors, just some helpful warnings and a linker error because you never defined the `printDatabase` overload that you use: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d810ca773d5f502

Comment: I am *positive* repeating this assignment: `student1[ NUM_GRADES ] = ...` is *not* going to get you what you're looking for (unless you're looking for *undefined behavior*). That index should be `i`. And `cout << setw( 4 ) << a[ i, j ];` isn't going to work either. Try `a[i][j]`. (and turn up your compiler warnings as high as they'll go).

Comment: Looks like database is a two dimensional array. But the line you marked as 44 uses only one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

so after looking it over I found a compiling error. The "printDatabase" definition and declaration do not match up. The declaration states the function as taking const parameters but the definition does not.

However once that is fixed there is the error at runtime. The issue is here

```
for ( i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++ )
    student1[ NUM_GRADES ] = rand() % 50 + 50;
```

student1 is being index at NUM_GRADES, which is the length of the student1 array. However since array indexing starts at 0 the last index would be NUM_GRADES - 1. So writing out of bounds of the array is taking place here. Although I believe looking at the code the behavior sought after is to index with i

```
for ( i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++ )
    student1[ i] = rand() % 50 + 50;
```